# GWT-Platform Gatekeeper and Nested Presenters

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform

I would like to know some things about gwtp gatekeeper:

1. if `canReveal()` method returns `false`, what happens? In my tests, i've been redirected to the defaultplace, i can change it?
2. having nested presenters, like:

   `MenuPresenter` - Only visible for admins.

   `HomePresenter` - Visible for admins and normal users.

   When the logged user is a normal user,  i want to only "not display" the menu presenter, is that possible?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 - "if canReveal() method returns false, what happens? In my tests, i've been redirected to the defaultplace, i can change it?"

From the [GWTP wiki](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/GettingStarted?tm=6#Blocking_some_presenters):

"The presenter handling errors is the one revealed by your custom PlaceManager's `revealErrorPlace` method. If you do not override that method, then it's the one revealed by your `revealDefaultPlace` method."

This is the default implementation of `revealErrorPlace`:

```
public void revealErrorPlace(String invalidHistoryToken) {
    revealDefaultPlace();
}
```

So you can override it in your custom PlaceManager and add more logic to it to redirect to any place you want.

---

2 - "When the logged user is a normal user, i want to only "not display"
the menu presenter, is that possible?"

You can hide the view in the presenter like this:

```
@Override
protected void onReset() {
    super.onReset();

    if (!user.getAdmin) {
        getView().asWidget().setVisible(false);
   }
}
```

(for PopupPresenters you must override the onReveal() method)

Comment: hmm, i ask it because I see one example that have 2 gatekeepers, one for admin and one for normal user...

Comment: Yes, you can have any number of gatekeepers, one for admin, one for a logged in user, etc. But I'm afraid I don't see your point.

Answer (score 1):

Uhm, I think we should  update the documentation.

You can also override revealUnauthorizedPlace, this will make sure you have a disctinc process for error handling and for security.

By default, revealUnauthorizedPlace calls revealsErrorPlace.